# SignalR.Orleans cause error in app.UseSignalR

Tags: signalr, orleans

I'm trying to use SignalR with MS Orleans backplane using this library https://github.com/OrleansContrib/SignalR.Orleans
When I added .AddOrleans() to AddSignalR() like the instruction in the readme file but it causes this error in the UseSignalR() code in Configure:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Orleans.IClusterClient' while attempting to activate 'SignalR.Orleans.DefaultClusterClientProvider'.'

ConfigureServices:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {            
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        services.AddSignalR().AddOrleans();
    }
```

Configure:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<Hubs.MainHub>("/main");
        });// this code work if I remove AddOrleans in ConfigureServices
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

upon inspection of the library code, the AddOrleans function code is this:

```
public static ISignalRBuilder AddOrleans(this ISignalRBuilder builder, IClusterClientProvider clientProvider = null)
    {
        if (clientProvider != null)
            builder.Services.AddSingleton(clientProvider);
        else
            builder.Services.TryAddSingleton<IClusterClientProvider, DefaultClusterClientProvider>();

        builder.Services.AddSingleton(typeof(HubLifetimeManager<>), typeof(OrleansHubLifetimeManager<>));
        return builder;
    }
```

Still I have no idea why it's not working since dependency injection is kinda new to me.

Answer (score 0):

The `DefaultClusterClientProvider` constructor expects an `IClusterClient` instance. The exception you're receiving indicates an `IClusterClient` instance is not registered in the DI container.

The example code you've posted doesn't appear to instantiate a cluster client. You probably need to add something like the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{            
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    services.AddSignalR().AddOrleans();

    var client = new ClientBuilder()
        ... // other client configuration options here
        .UseSignalR()
        .Build();
    services.AddSingleton<IClusterClient>(client);
}
```

The singleton registration should make the cluster client available to the `DefaultClusterClientProvider` constructor in addition to other objects (like your ASP.NET Core controllers).

Comment: Yeah, I actually did exactly like you suggest and it fixed error in the question. But whenever I tried to call a Grain it gives me error "Grain reference not found" (can't remember the exact error since I don't use Signalr.Orleans anymore). If I remove SignalR.Orleans everything is normal.

Comment: Binh Luong, if you have a sample application and you would happy be to help you to set it up.

PS. I m one of the authors of Signalr.Orleans. 

For future reference when you have these kinds of issues, ideally open an issue on the git project so we could easily help you out.

Comment: @ClaytonLautier I attached a screenshot of the error and the demo project in the related issue on the git project. I thought of creating the issue over there but the issue page does not seem very active to me so I decide to post here.